# how can I keep a floating view always on top of my app?

Tags: android

If  my app have the permission ,"android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW", you know my problem can be resolved esaily . But on most of the android phone from China , the user should grant this permission manually . so is there a solution while my app has not the permission ?  I just want the view floating on my app not the whole system . I have a bad way : let my app only contain one activity , and make all the pages just fragments  in the activity.

Comment: Targeting to lower api would help as earlier this permission was not needed

Comment: "Some phone like Redmi, Oppo etc. its all have given more security permission, without user permission its not granted."

Answer (score 0):

There are no alternative solution of it. Almost all device above api 21 taking grant permission of user to show floating icon over any another app. Some phone like Redmi, Oppo etc. its all have given more security permissio, without user permission its not granted.